# Automating tasking in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Suppose I have a file in this format in excel:

```
A            B              C
1            2              3
4            5              9
```

where A,B and C are the standard column headers in excel. The values in C are defined as sum(A,B) in excel. What I want to do is to automatically input a series of numbers for A and B and print the values of C in a new sheet. The above is just an example of what I want to do. The formula of C could be a complicated function(i.e. sum(A+B)*0.1/(1000)). Any ideas how to automate this?

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically input a series of numbers"? Where do these numbers come from? Is there a generating formula (1,2,3,4…)? If you just want to move the values over, you can copy the entire range and do a paste special… values. I don't think that is what you mean though - so can you clear up my confusion?

Comment: The numbers already exist in a sheet within the excel file. This is not my actual problem but a simpler version. Basically, I want to substitute values from one sheet into another sheet where they are transformed into output values into yet another sheet. I want to be able to automate this process without manually copying the values from one sheet to another sheet

Comment: So do you just want to "automatically copy"? What is the trigger for this? A button press? A macro that is run manually? A file that is opened? Is the destination a new sheet? In the same workbook? Newly created? Does it have a specific name?

Answer (score 1):

The following VBA code will do something like you ask for (it replaces the formula with the values - if you don't want that, then use `Paste` instead of `PasteSpecial`).

```
Sub copyAtoB()
  Dim sh1 As Worksheet
  Dim sh2 As Worksheet
  Dim r1 As Range

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False          ' stops screen flickering during update

  Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")   ' your source sheet
  Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")   ' your destination sheet
  Set r1 = Range(sh1.[a1], sh1.[c1].End(xlDown)) ' select from A1 to last contiguous cell in C
  sh1.Activate                                ' make sure source sheet is active
  r1.Copy                                     ' copy the range defined above
  sh2.Activate                                ' make the destination sheet active
  sh2.[a1].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues       ' copy just the values (no equation)

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False          ' turn screen updating on again

End Sub
```

It should be obvious how to adapt this to your needs - if it is not, use comments to ask for clarification.

Comment: I think activating the sheets are not needed since you already properly set the Object Variables which is best practice @Floris

Comment: @L42 you may be right. I did not have a chance to test this and I know that Excel is a bit finicky with copy/paste operations. I can test later and may update my answer then.